# How to use ${workspaceFolder} in VS Code workspace settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My Visual Studio Code workspace configuration file MyProj.code-workspace is stored under svn in:

MyProj/trunk/Tools/VSCode

and contains:

```
"folders": [
{
    "path": "C:\\SVNProj\\MyProj\\trunk"
}
```

so that the entire trunk appears in the workspace.

This path is not convenient because it becomes incorrect when merged to a branch.  So I want to do something like:

```
"folders": [
{
    "${workspaceFolder}"    
}
```

but that literally shows '${workspaceFolder}' in the file tree.

How can I set the displayed folder to two levels above the path of the workspace config file?

Comment: Sounds like a valid feature request for the VSCode repo, if there isn't one already.

Comment: I have decided to simply use a single folder rather than a multi-root workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You have process these settings manually:

Like in my extension:

https://github.com/default-writer/filetestonsave/blob/main/src/extension.ts

```js
        const filePath = document.fileName;
        const fileWorkspaceFolder = vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(vscode.Uri.file(filePath));
        const cmd = this._testCommands.find(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(document.languageId)); // Get the files and command values
        let commandText = cmd[document.languageId];
        try {
            if (fileWorkspaceFolder) {
                if (commandText.includes('${workspaceFolder}')) {
                    commandText = commandText.replace('${workspaceFolder}', workspaceFolderUri?.uri.fsPath ?? '');
                }
                if (commandText.includes('${workspaceFolderBasename}')) {
                    commandText = commandText.replace('${workspaceFolderBasename}', workspaceFolderUri?.name ?? '');
                }
                if (commandText.includes('${file}')) {
                    commandText = commandText.replace('${file}', document.uri.fsPath);
                }
                if (commandText.includes('${fileWorkspaceFolder}')) {
                    commandText = commandText.replace('${fileWorkspaceFolder}', fileWorkspaceFolder?.uri.fsPath ?? '');
                }
                if (commandText.includes('${relativeFileDirname}')) {
                    commandText = commandText.replace('${relativeFileDirname}', path.relative(fileWorkspaceFolder?.uri.fsPath ?? '', path.dirname(filePath)));
                }
            }
            if (commandText.includes('${fileBasename}')) {
                commandText = commandText.replace('${fileBasename}', vscode.workspace.asRelativePath(filePath));
            }
            if (commandText.includes('${fileBasenameNoExtension}')) {
                commandText = commandText.replace('${fileBasenameNoExtension}', path.basename(filePath, path.extname(filePath)));
            }
            if (commandText.includes('${fileExtname}')) {
                commandText = commandText.replace('${fileExtname}', filePath.split('.').pop());
            }
            if (commandText.includes('${fileDirname}')) {
                commandText = commandText.replace('${fileDirname}', path.dirname(filePath));
            }
            if (commandText.includes('${fileDirnameBasename}')) {
                commandText = commandText.replace('${fileDirnameBasename}', path.basename(path.dirname(filePath)));
            }
            const regex = /\${env:(.*?)}/g;
            const matches = commandText.match(regex);
            if (matches) {
                const resolvedString = matches.reduce((acc: string, match: string) => {
                    const variableName = match.slice(6, -1);
                    const variableValue = process.env[variableName] ?? '';
                    return acc.replace(match, variableValue);
                }, commandText);
                commandText = resolvedString;
            }
```